# Permission for ajax Calls to a folder contains .htaccess

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a folder named *chatlogs* on my root (path: root/chatlogs)
and a .htaccess file in *chatlogs* folder that Denies any request from url to the contents of chatlogs.
Now i wanna allow ajax calls to this folder. (Imagine some files named : log0.html , log1.html , ... in chatlogs folder)

htaccess:

```
Deny from all
```

my ajax call:

```
function loadLog(){     
   $.ajax( {
     url: "chatlogs/log0.html",
     cache: false,
     success: function( html ){
        $(" #chatbox ").html( html ); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div   
              }             
     },
   });
setInterval ( loadLog, 1500 );
```

Apparently the loadlog() function has no access to *chatlogs* folder.
How can i allow this ajax call to enter in *chatlogs* folder? Should i add some lines in .htaccess file ???
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ajax call is no different by any other call except some sent headers, that easily can be spoofed. Why do you want to deny the content, but allow for ajax calls, it's practically the same as allow to all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

edit your .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest ajax
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=ajax
```

...
SetEnvIfNoCase - allow you to conditionally set environment variables accessible by scripts and apache based on the value of HTTP Headers, Other Variables, and Request information. In our case: if there's header "X-Requested-With" the environmental variable "ajax" will be set.
Allow from env=ajax (allows access only for requests with above headers)

Comment: Good solution but you need to add detail what those 4 lines do and why it works.

Comment: lines 2 and 3 must already exist in user's .htaccess. So, I'll explain the 1 and 4th line